# If $u \in L^2(\Omega)$, then $\text{sign}u \in L^2(\Omega)$?

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

If $\Omega$ is a bounded domain and $u$ is in $L^2$, why is $\text{sign}(u) \in L^2?$

I am only stuck with the measurabilituy part. the integral is obviously finite on a bounded domain.

Comment: How do you define $\operatorname{sign}$ of a function?

Comment: I think $+1$ and $-1$ in the obvious part, and when the function is $0$, the sign can be either.

Comment: So you can write this function as a linear combination of characteristic function, can't you?

Comment: So: you need to show: if $u$ is measurable, then $\text{sign}\;u$ is also measurable.  Do you have real or complex values here?

Comment: @GEdgar It is all real here. Maybe as Davide suggested I write it as a sum of characteristics, then it turns to checking whether $\{ u < 0\}$ and $\{u >0 \}$ are measurable sets. This should be true since $u$ is measurable. However, if I defined sign in a different way I'm not sure how it changes things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$sign^{-1}$ maps 1 and -1 (measurable point sets) to the half intervals [0, $\infty$) and (-$\infty$, 0) respectively, which are measurable sets. These may be open or closed at 0, either way sign is measurable. Since f is measurable Ran(f) is measurable and $f^{-1}$ of either of these half lines (which are measurable sets) intersected with Ran(f) must be measurable. The composition of sign and f is then measurable.